# user-account-specific protection using DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider in C#

Tags: encryption

I have to create a C# utility to encrypt and decrypt using **user-account-specific protection** method instead of machine based approach.

I am using DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider as a protection provider.

Since using DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider, by default machine based encryption is performed... how do i make a it user account based encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute *useMachineProtection* to your configProtectedData/providers/add element in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configProtectedData defaultProvider="SampleProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="SampleProvider"
        type="System.Configuration.DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
        useMachineProtection="false" />
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
</configuration>
```